# ONESIDE Only in FRONTMATTER?

Tags: double-sided, single-sided

One picks either ONESIDE or TWOSIDE at the beginning of BOOK, but can FRONTMATTER and MAINMATTER have different options? For example,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{TEXT}
\author{TEXT}
\date{TEXT}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter        % Must use oneside
\maketitle
\lipsum
\mainmatter         % Must use twoside
\chapter{TEXT}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

DOCUMENTCLASS here uses ONESIDE for all pages, but MAINMATTER must use TWOSIDE instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geometry` package provides the command `\newgeometry`, which you can use to switch to `twoside`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry} % <-- here
\title{TEXT}
\author{TEXT}
\date{TEXT}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter          % Must use oneside
\maketitle
\lipsum
\mainmatter           % Must use twoside
\newgeometry{twoside} % <-- here

\chapter{TEXT}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in MAINMATTER, the code suppresses both page numbers and headers in even pages—they're not suppressed in odd pages.

Comment: Changing the geometry that radically mid document causes a lot of problems. You probably need to reset the pagestyle as well.